# Menu not shown with specific resolutions

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've created a default (thus I took what visual studio 2017 created when I created the project) master and sub pages website.

In the masterpage I put in a menu using a combination of divs and tables.

It all works well EXCEPT if I reduce the window size so that the width of the window is about 1280 px. Then suddenly the menu items are no longer shown and also nothing clickable on the menu bar.

One thing that stands out to me is: The menu still would have had plenty of space, but the menu items are still not shown. Only the black bar of the menu (background color is set to black for the table).

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
                    <asp:Table ID="MenuTable" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="Contacts" NavigateUrl="~/Forms/Contacts?#DynamicLinkReplace">Kontakte</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="PingLink" NavigateUrl='javascript:void(window.open("~/forms/ping.aspx", "Ping to XXXXX", "width=640, height=480"));' >Ping</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="RemoteLink" Target="_blank">Remote</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='~/Forms/JournalT.aspx?#DynamicLinkReplace' id="JournalT">Journal T</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='~/Forms/JournalH.aspx?#DynamicLinkReplace' id="JournalH">Journal H</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell ID="MenuCellEnvelopeClearance">
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='~/Forms/Clearance.aspx?#DynamicLinkReplace' id="MenuEnvelopeClearance">Freigabe</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="DetailsLink" NavigateUrl='~/Forms/Details.aspx?#DynamicLinkReplace'>Details</asp:HyperLink>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                        </asp:TableRow>
                    </asp:Table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

.CSS is not shown as it only is used for colouring and text size (font-size 14 px, line height 1.4285).

Now my question is twofold. 1.) What is the exact cause of such a phenomenon (so that I don't stumble upon it again) and 2.) What can I do to correct this behaviour?

Comment: based on some of your CSS class names, are you perhaps using bootstrap? It has responsive design features which may be the cause of your issue. The menu normally gets compressed into a clickable/touchable "hamburger" icon which would then expand to show the items when activated. You need to make sure you include necessary markup in the page for that to appear. Bootstrap docs or tutorials should show you how to set it up properly

Comment: yes I use bootstrap (is used by default it seems).  Ah ok so by default it does that BUT the hamburger icon needs to be manually set else it is as in my case that you don't see anything at all. correct so @ADyson ?

Comment: Yes you have to include the necessary HTML which is used to draw it. As I say, consult the bootstrap docs, you should find examples

Comment: @ADyson that was it. in essence I needed to remove the collapse from the div and it works now as intended. tnx

Answer (score -1):

In your Default Style sheet Consider this code

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

  #Container{
    style:block;
  }
}
```

May be your any `css` or bootstrap contain the Code of `min-width` or `max-width` properties
In future check the style sheet

Comment: This is a guess rather than an actual solution